# adapting set label command in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have some problem with adapting the set label command as per my requirement. I have to insert a label on the top left of the plot. My label contain mathemaical exponent. so I used the following command

```
set label 1 '$\times10^{-7}$' at graph 0,1.025
```

I have used epslatex output terminal and the result I have got is not as expected.
[image]

Comment: This looks like a latex problem rather than a gnuplot problem. I have no trouble rendering your label with pdflatex and the `epslatex` terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use double '\' (\\). And should have to put a white space between `\\times` and `10` (but I'm not sure now).

```
set label 1 "$\\times 10^{-7}$" at graph 0,1.025
```

(PS.: I prefer `cdot` instead of `times` ;-) )

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working quite well and I consider your suggestion about \cdot.

Comment: No escaping should be required when using single quotes, which is what the OP posted. There must be something else involved here.